# SSRS - Custom assembly in location other than server bin directory

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is it possible to deploy a custom assembly to a location other than the Reporting Service's bin directory?

I know that deploying to the GAC would likely work, but I'm more curious about using an arbitrary directory on the server dedicated to deploying custom assemblies.

I'm not opposed to altering any rs config files, if a possible solution involves that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155034.aspx), you must deploy to the \bin directory or install in the GAC ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155034.aspx).) Those are your only options.

The Microsoft SQL Server forum has an identical discussion going on.  A Microsoft support engineer [gave the same answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/787fb91a-1845-443e-8f87-2bef0e08d268): it can't be done.